# cutting the 7" TFT screen

Tags: touchscreen

The official 7" screen is 1.5 mm to wide (longer side) in order to fit into my car radio-adapter. Is it possible to cut 1.5 mm from one side without destroying the screen (I would try to sand it)

Comment: Please add that as an answer and then accept it so that other people can find it easily in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/dont-try-this-at-home-how-not-to-hack-the-raspberry-pi-display/), stating that it should not be done:

> Since then I’ve seen a few enquiries via Twitter as to whether the glass could be “resized”, particularly to make it compatible with the European DIN standard for car audio head units. (We expect to see a lot of car media centres using the display.) The official answer is, “No, you will break it and void your warranty.” And I’ll leave it at that :)